# python to select nested dictionary value

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to pull a value that's nested out, looking get the value at "minPrice" but I don't seem to be able to isolate it.

```
data = {'symbol': 'MKRUSD', 
        'quoteCommissionPrecision': 4,
        'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 
        'isSpotTradingAllowed': True,
        'isMarginTradingAllowed': False,
        'filters': 
            [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.0001', 'maxPrice': '100000.0000', 'tickSize': '0.0001'}, 
             {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5},
             {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '900000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'},
             {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.0000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5},
             {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10},
             {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200},
             {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}],
 'permissions': ['SPOT']}

print(symbol_info["symbol"])
print(symbol_info["filters"]["filterType"]["LOT_SIZE"]["minQty"])
```

I don't think it's json because, when I do type, it comes back as a python dictionary, and the False/True seem to look that way. But maybe it is, and I need to read it somehow first?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using the wrong variable to access the data. Assign data to symbol_info variable and then access it or use the data variable directly.

```
print(data["symbol"])
```

Second, the filtertype is a dict inside a list. So you have to use index to access it.

```
print(type(data["filters"])) #<- this is list
print(data["filters"][2]["filterType"])
print(data["filters"][2]["minQty"])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Hope it helps

```
data = {'symbol': 'MKRUSD', 
        'quoteCommissionPrecision': 4,
        'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 
        'isSpotTradingAllowed': True,
        'isMarginTradingAllowed': False,
        'filters': 
            [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.0001', 'maxPrice': '100000.0000', 'tickSize': '0.0001'}, 
            {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5},
            {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '900000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'},
            {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.0000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5},
            {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10},
            {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200},
            {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}],'permissions': ['SPOT']}
for key,val in data["filters"][0].items():
  if key =="minPrice":
    print(val)
```